# Monitoring that process runs and active?

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, health-monitoring

We have a number of rabbitmq consumers running. And I want to make sure that every one of those processes is working.

What are the best industry applied approaches for that?
We are considering using prometheus for that, is that the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You can go the Prometheus route. Use [this](https://www.rabbitmq.com/prometheus.html) link to get started, which would fairly quickly set you up with the ability to monitor RabbitMQ w/ Prometheus.
You can use [AlertManager](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/alertmanager/) to setup alerts on failed processes and top that with automations to make sure you have service continuity.
HTH.